# How can I push a branch to remote after resolving rebase conflicts without using force push?

Tags: git, github

I have a Git branch with an open pull request in GitHub. But I can't merge it because GitHub complains that there are some conflicting files with latest master. Then I pull master and rebase master to my local branch and during rebase, I got conflicts. So I resolved the conflicts and when trying to push the branch to origin, my push was rejected and error says that the tip of my current branch is behind. However when I do force push it will get accepted. Anyway I can achieve this without using force push?

Comment: You rewrote the history of your branch, therefore you have to force push in order for it work.

Comment: The need for `--force` comes from your rebase, not from conflict resolution. It would have also be rejected after a non-conflicting rebase, but would **not** have been rejected on a (conflicting or not) merge.

Answer (score 2):

Since rebasing alters history, some sort of force-push is required.

Luckily, there's `git push --force-with-lease`, which will still reject the push if another commit was added to the branch in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rebasing you should merge, this will not rewrite the history and you will be able to push it without `force push`. If you don't want to merge then unfortunately there is no way I know to achieve this without `force push`.

Answer (score 0):

Push your code to a new branch on GitHub.
`git push origin old-conflicts-branch:new-remote-branch`

Then you can continue working with the new branch. The old branch is still there, so you can delete it or keep it as backup.